# Class has no initializers (Xcode 6.3)

Tags: xcode, swift, init

Trying to figure out errors after updating to Xcode 6.3. I have a class thats getting the error 'Class has no initializers' could anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
class TodayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, BWWalkthroughViewControllerDelegate {


var events: [EKEvent] = []
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
var pttCalendar: EKCalendar?

let walkthroughVC : BWWalkthroughViewController?

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    requestCalendarAccess()

    let firstLaunch = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("FirstLaunch")
    if firstLaunch  {
        println("Not first launch.")
    }
    else {
        showWalkthrough()
        println("First launch, setting NSUserDefault.")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "FirstLaunch")
    }


    self.tableView.rowHeight = 50

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EE, MMM dd"
    let dateForLabel = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    self.title = dateForLabel
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the override `func init()`

Answer (score 0):

You need an initialiser to set the value

```
let walkthroughVC : BWWalkthroughViewController?
```

Setting that as a `var` will remove the error. It will of course default to `nil`.